# UIImageView not presenting image in correct orientation in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, orientation

I have tried alot of solutions but non has worked yet

Heres what i am doing:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
        //imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

        NSOperatingSystemVersion ios8_0_0 = (NSOperatingSystemVersion){8, 0, 0};

          //This was suggested in answer of some question of stackoverflow
        if ([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:ios8_0_0])
        {
            if([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp)
            {
                if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
                {
                    [[UIDevice currentDevice]setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight] forKey:@"orientation"];
                }
                else
                {
                    [[UIDevice currentDevice]setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft] forKey:@"orientation"];
                }
            }
        }

        self.imagePickerController = imagePicker;
        [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

When the above didnt worked i tried some thing else while saving picture

```
 NSData *imgPngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgPngData];
     imgPngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [_profilePicture setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage] scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp]];
```

but no effect on behavior. This is what happening Iam taking this image. 
[image: Iam taking this image]

And this what appearing on my imageView
[image]

Kindly suggest some thing. Thanking all of you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same problem solved it by integrating below code. Reference [link](https://gist.github.com/alex-cellcity/1531596) for the code

```
- (UIImage *)fixOrientation {

    // No-op if the orientation is already correct
    if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return self;

    // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
    // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
            break;
    }

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.height, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            break;
    }

    // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
    // calculated above.
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.size.width, self.size.height,
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0,
                                             CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage),
                                             CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage));
//    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
//    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.size.width, self.size.height,
//                                            8, self.size.width,
//                                             colorspace,
//                                             kCGImageAlphaNone);
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            // Grr...
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.height,self.size.width), self.CGImage);
            break;

        default:
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width,self.size.height), self.CGImage);
            break;
    }

    // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
    CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    return img;
}
```

Comment: Why normal functions arent working for anyone ? is there any good reason to implement this tweak ?

Comment: The comments below it are not very good so many people have wrote about app crash due to memory. Did you also faced the same ?

Comment: Yes if you try to snap the photos so many times then it might be possible application get crashesd.. Frankly speaking don't know exact reason for this implementation... Tried to get root cause but didn't get it anywhere.. If you found anywhere please share with me..

Comment: I have tried almost all the functions which apple provides for rotations but hard luck for me i guess nothing has worked yet. How did you implement this in your when i try to it has so many fixes and warning that it is not letting me to even try this one

Comment: Its category to the UIImage class.. Uploaded a code https://www.dropbox.com/s/dxd2aebvv8h9nh9/Orientation.zip?dl=0 over here..

Comment: Add files to your code.. Import it in your controller & call it using your UIImage object. It will return UIImage object with proper orientation..

Comment: NSData *imgPngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgPngData];
    image = image.fixOrientation;
    _profilePicture.image = nil;
    [_profilePicture setImage:image];
It didnt work ;/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79091/discussion-between-mq-and-nilesh-patel).

Answer (score -1):

Use this may help you

```
 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {

        [uploadImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        uploadImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        uploadImage=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        uploadImage = [self imageWithImage:uploadImage scaledToWidth:uploadImageView.frame.size.width];
        uploadImageView.image=uploadImage;

        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    }
```